# NSXMLParser & Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

My xml is

```
<categoryname>Baby</categoryname>  
<id>244</id>                      
<categoryname>Boats & Watercraft</categoryname>  
<idc>1026</id>
```

I am getting first two nodes.My problem is the third node i am getting **Boats** only (parser foundCharacters) and **&** kills the nsxmlparser. I am searching this forum and other websites most of them post use **`&amp;`** instead of **&** in xml . My xml is coming from server  and i wont update  xml now.Is there any other option to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on sending invalid XML from your server this should solve it:

```
[xmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"]:
// parse xmlString
[categoryName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"]:
```

Comment: its correct.and one more thing i am trimming whitespace at the end of that string.i am using [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n\t"]]; this code will trim  middle of the string too.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml might be coming from some php script then before sending it you have to make change in your script that when & character occurs it substitute with other character like $ or any other and then send it. And when  you parse that xml change that symbol to your required symbol.
I have also done the same thing.

Comment: our xml is asp script.we don't have a server access.already  our client give an url thats why i am asking any other option